# New String vs String s = "something" , what's the difference ?

Tags: java, string, new-operator

Consider the code :

```
public class Strings {

    public static void createStr()
    {
        String s1 = new String("one");
        String s2 = "one";

        System.out.println(s1);
        System.out.println(s2);
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        createStr();
    }

}
```

What's the difference between `String s1 = new String("one");` and `String s2 = "one";` ?

Answer (score 7):

```
  String s1 = new String("one"); // will be created on the heap and not interned unless .intern() is called explicityly. 
  String s2 = "one";  // will be created in the String pool and interned automatically by the compiler.
```

Comment: "will be created on the heap"---maybe. It could also be allocated on the stack. This is outside of programmer's control.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - Could you be more specific please.

Comment: Escape Analysis may prove that the string can safely be allocated on the stack.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - oh. Never knew that.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

`String s1 = new String("one");` create a new string object in memory, while `String s2 = "one";` use the string pool.

It is not a good practice to use new keyword when dealing with string in java.